# How to handle errors from onFailure method in Retrofit?

Tags: android, callback, retrofit

When making a http-request with Retrofit sometimes the `onFailure` method (from the `Callback` interface) is called instead of the `onResponse`. The problem is that the `Throwable` returned in this method comes with `null` fields. Meaning, the `getMessage()`, `getLocalizedMessage()` and the `getCause()` methods, all return `null`.

Is there a known reason of why the `onFailure()` is called like this?
Is there another way of knowing why the `onFailure()` method was called?

Comment: check out this link. it will help you : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Answer (score 2):

When executing the call, retrofit executes third party code in the form of adapters and converters.  Because of that, it is hard to predict all the various exceptions it might encounter.  When `onFailure` is called, something threw an exception - either retrofit, okhttp, or an adapter or converter.  You can handle it much like you would a thrown exception except you don't need to catch it.  When you are debugging, use `t.printStackTrace()` to get a handle on what went wrong and if it is preventable.  You can also look for specific exceptions by checking the type of the exception. For example, `IOException` is common because of network failures --

```
if (t instanceof IOException) {
    // Handle IO exception, maybe check the network and try again.
}
```